# Why do I get an error "app.use() requires a generator function" using koa-views middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I installed koa, then installed koa-views.
After that I copied example code from the koa-views docs and pasted it into index.js

```
'use strict';

const koa = require('koa');
const app = koa();

var views = require('koa-views');

// Must be used before any router is used
app.use(views(__dirname + '/views', {
    map: {
        html: 'underscore'
    }
}));
app.use(function* (next) {
    this.state = {
        session: this.session,
        title: 'app'
    };
    yield this.render('user', {
        user: 'John'
    });
});
```

When I try to run this code with command `node index.js` I get an error:

[image]

What's the problem? Why doesn't it work?

p.s.

```
node version: v6.9.5; 
koa version: 1.2.5; 
koa-views version: 5.2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing `npm install koa-views@4.1.0` seems like there might be something different with the new version. See [here](https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router/issues/207) for where I got the solution.

I tried it, and I no longer got the error.

Comment: Thaks a lot. It helped!

Comment: Koa 2 uses `async` functions instead of generator functions for its middleware. When you use middleware like `koa-views`, you need to make sure you use the right version depending on which version of Koa you are using. `koa-views@4.1.0@` still uses generator functions for its middleware, which is why it works here.